Databricks SQL warehouse python udf giving timeout where when making REST API call
I have below use-case

UC enable workspace
Create python udf that will make REST api using request python lib
parse response and return

I was following below document
https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-ddl-create-sql-function.html
ERROR that I'm getting is
Failed to connect to https://www.google.com: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.xx.x.xx', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7ec9b1a73340>, 'Connection to xxx.xx.xx.xx timed out. (connect timeout=10)'))

